# Recurrent call to a function until it returns None

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I often encounter a pattern so I was wondering if there is any convenient method in Scala library for it.

Let it be a function `f: A => Option[B]`. I would like to do a recurrent call to `f` beginning with a starting `x`, `f(f(f(x).get).get...)`, until `f` returns `None` and keep the last non-`None` value.

I wrote an implementation for this:

```
@tailrec
def recurrentCallUntilNone[B](f: B => Option[B], x: B): B = f(x) match {
  case Some(y) => recurrentCallUntilNone(f, y)
  case None => x
}
```

Is this already implemented in the standard library?

A usage example for this could be for a list (Zipper) which keeps the current position. By calling `next`, `None` is returned if there are no elements after the current position or an `Option` for the same list, but with current position incremented. By using the above method, an `end` method can be constructed that seeks the list to the end.

Comment: It's not in the library, and you're doing it the right way.

Comment: This is almost an [`unfold`](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.at/2009/09/unfoldleft-and-right.html). But it doesn't seem to occur in any libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing looks like a very specific type of [trampoline](http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/04/tail-calls-tailrec-and-trampolines.html). The more general case uses functions wrapped in case classes instead of an `Option` and supports different argument and return types.

As Calin-Andrei points out trampolines are available in the standard library using the [TailCalls object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.TailCalls%24).

From the first link:

```
def even2(n: Int): Bounce[Boolean] = {
  if (n == 0) Done(true)
  else Call(() => odd2(n - 1))
}
def odd2(n: Int): Bounce[Boolean] = {
  if (n == 0) Done(false)
  else Call(() => even2(n - 1))
}
trampoline(even2(9999))

sealed trait Bounce[A]
case class Done[A](result: A) extends Bounce[A]
case class Call[A](thunk: () => Bounce[A]) extends Bounce[A]

def trampoline[A](bounce: Bounce[A]): A = bounce match {
  case Call(thunk) => trampoline(thunk())
  case Done(x) => x
}
```

Now with the standard library

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def even2(n: Int): TailRec[Boolean] = {
  if (n == 0) done(true)
  else tailcall(odd2(n - 1))
}
def odd2(n: Int): TailRec[Boolean] = {
  if (n == 0) done(false)
  else tailcall(even2(n - 1))
}
even2(9999).result
```

Comment: I didn't know about trampolines, so thank you for that. I found that the current version of the Scala library supports them through [`TailCalls`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.TailCalls$). Your answer is the closest to what I want. Can you modify it such that it uses the trampolines from the Scala library? Then I can accept your answer.

Comment: Wow I didn't know they were added to the standard library. StackOverflow is great I answer a question and learn something new at the same time :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Stream.iterate(Some(x)) { x => x.flatMap(f _) }.takeWhile { _.isDefined }.last
```

**UPDATE**

Or even neater IMHO (only single traversal):

```
val result = {
  val xs = Stream.iterate(Some(x)) { x => x.flatMap(f _) }
  (xs zip xs.tail) collectFirst {
    case (Some(x), None) => x
  } get
}
```

Note that it is safe to call `collectFirst` because we cannot start with a `None` (otherwise an infinite loop would be possible).

Answer (score 1):

in case of a beauty contest, you can build a function that transforms an existing one into the monster you were talking about through the use of currying.

```
def composeUntilTheEnd[B](f: Option[B] => Option[B])(x: Option[B]): Option[B] = 
        if (f(x) != None) composeUntilTheEnd(f)(f(x))
        else x

def ff = composeUntilTheEnd((x:Option[Int]) => x)_
```

Now calling `ff` you get the intended behaviour.

Comment: I don't think this is any more beautiful that the implementation given by the asker. Also, if the function is making side effects, then this solution is doing f(x) twice which might be unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you could create a steam from you options and then use stream functions on it to get the last defined element. (Or rather the last defined element before the undefined element)

```
def options[B](f: B => Option[B], initialValue: Option[B]): Stream[Option[B]] = {
  initialValue #:: options(f, initialValue.map(f(_)).flatten)
}

options.takeWhile(_.isDefined).last
```